# Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: java, user-interface

I'm just starting to learn making GUIs and this is the first problem:
when i try:

```
    Toolkit tk = new Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
```

I get this error

> Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit cannot be resolved to a type

I am on Mac Yosemite with Eclipse "Luna Service Release 1 (4.4.1)" what ever that is.
if i run java -version on the terminal i get :

> java version "1.7.0_71"
>
> Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_71-b14)
>
> Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.71-b01, mixed mode)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `new`. You're not invoking a constructor, you're calling a factory method.

Comment: Thanx everyone, the problem was with the "new" operator.

Answer (score 3):

You call [`Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Toolkit.html#getDefaultToolkit%28%29) without `new` like

```
Toolkit tk = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
```

And, it doesn't hurt to make sure you have the import

```
import java.awt.Toolkit;
```

Comment: If he didn't have the import he would be getting `Toolkit cannot be resolved to a type`.

Answer (score 0):

if imports are missing in eclipse:
click on the `Toolkit` class - then press **ctrl+1** - now chosse the quickfix offered. That will import the class automatically
or: press **ctrl+shift+o** - choose the import you need

Comment: There's no evidence that he doesn't have the import already: on the contrary; and you've missed the real error.